# How do you center everything

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Is there a way to center everything in a LaTeX document even the text?

Answer (score 6):

You can put a `\centering` command right after the beginning of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \centering
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\lipsum{1}`? Did you mean `\lipsum[1]`?

Comment: \centering centers each:  \begin{align*}\end{align*} but inside of align* how do you center?

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, my bad, but now I see it is better without argument, optional or not :-)

Comment: @user1531503 -- if you want to center each line of a multi-line math display, don't use `align*`, use `gather*`.  i haven't time to research the details of how the `amsmath` structures interact with `\centering`, but `gather` all by itself centers each line of its content, so shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: Crosspost http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=26055&p=89285#p89285

Answer (score 6):

Apart from centering normal text, you probably want to center also sectioning titles.

This can be done by loading the `sectsty` package and issuing

```
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
```

Also, for centering multi-line math, use the `gather` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\centering
\chapter{A chapter}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\begin{gather*}
a+b=c\\
x^2+y^2=z^2
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]