# Centered LaTeX program written

Tags: math-mode

I have a somewhat working LaTeX program written.
One thing I would like to be better is the centering of the `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}`.

I tried `\begin{gather*}...\end{gather*}` but I can not get it to work with heavy math Latex code just text.

I would also like to know the Latex code for a single space.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{gather*}
Given:\\
3 consecutive R vectors.\\
\\
Find:\\ 
Middle Velocity vector and Keplerian Elements.\\
\\
Solution:\\
\end{gather*}
\begin{align*}
R1=(X1,Y1,Z1)\\
R2=(X2,Y2,Z2)\\
R3=(X3,Y3,Z3)\\
C_{12} &= R1 \times R2 = \begin{vmatrix}%
    \hat{x}& \hat{y}& \hat{z}\\
     X1&Y1&Z1\\
     X2&Y2&Z2\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
C_{12}x &= (Y1 * Z2 - Z1 * Y2)\\
C_{12}y &= (Z1 * X2 - X1 * Z2)\\
C_{12}z &= (X1 * Y2 - Y1 * X2)  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `gather*` works if you remove those `&` before `=`, for example, `C_{12}x = (Y1 * Z2 - Z1 * Y2)\\ `

Comment: Should the text be centered as well, or just the math material?

Comment: this appears to be a follow-on to [How do you center everything](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235254/579).  it's usually appreciated if that is noted in the newer question.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `gather*` without the alignment point, i.e., remove those `&` before `=`. There is no point in aligning when you want every thing to be centered.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\centering
Given:

3 consecutive R vectors.

Find:

Middle Velocity vector and Keplerian Elements.

Solution:
\begin{gather*}
R1=(X1,Y1,Z1)\\
R2=(X2,Y2,Z2)\\
R3=(X3,Y3,Z3)\\
C_{12} = R1 \times R2 = \begin{vmatrix}%
    \hat{x}& \hat{y}& \hat{z}\\
     X1&Y1&Z1\\
     X2&Y2&Z2\\
\end{vmatrix}\\
C_{12}x = (Y1 * Z2 - Z1 * Y2)\\
C_{12}y = (Z1 * X2 - X1 * Z2)\\
C_{12}z = (X1 * Y2 - Y1 * X2)
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more on horizontal spaces, read [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/11232) by Werner.

Comment: Well, the textual parts should be fixed, shouldn't they?

Comment: @egreg I thought they are just for demo. Fixed.

Comment: One last question: How do you put in a single space in LaTeX?

Comment: @user1531503 Single space where? Please read: [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354)

Comment: @user1531503 And please also read: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) :)

Comment: you might be interested in [Add a "Space" in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/236320)

Comment: @Johannes_B I won't even think about it `:-)`